# How to prevent submit and call a webservice on Enter keypressed in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, textbox, submit

Is there a simple way to turn off form submit behaviour of the page when ENTER is pressed

while I am focused to textbox? What I want to achieve is to call a web-service without submiting the page when ENTER is pressed in a specific textbox in my aspx page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is tagged as JavaScript and not JQuery: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/enter.html

That's the first link at http://www.google.ee/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=prevent+enter+on+forms+javascript

Comment: Be careful with claims about something being the first link.  Google tends to use your search history to tweak your searches.  Heck, this weekend I did a search on my phone, then did an identical (verified, twice) search on a desktop.  The phone gave me results, the desktop claimed there weren't any matches.  Both were done at google.com.    Other than that, +1